# Selecting single instance of resizable bar in jQuery with same class name

Tags: jquery

I have multiple resizable bars that I need to pull the initial size from but keep getting that the element is undefined. Here is my code so far.

```
 <div class="r_bar"><span class="resizable" style="width: 34%;"><div class="marker"><p></p></div></span></div>
```

...and my jQuery that I've worked on with the help from Eskimo.

```
$(function(){
var initialWidth = $('.r_bar').siblings().find('span').css('width').replace('%', '');
initialWidth = parseInt(initialWidth);
var dragging = false;

$('.resizable').mousedown(function(e){
    dragging = true;
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();

    $this = $(e.currentTarget);
    e.preventDefault();

    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        if (dragging == true){
            $this.css("width",e.pageX - parentOffset.left);
            var percentageChange = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) / initialWidth * 100
            $('.marker p').html(percentageChange.toFixed(0));
        }       
    });
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if (dragging){
        dragging = false;
    }
});
});
```

Currently what this does is makes all instances of the bar update their numbers even if they aren't being dragged. It also won't display the initialWidth upon page load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`$('.marker p')` you are selecting all 'p' elements in all elements aving the class `.marker`. If you want to modify only one bar, what you can do is something like that :

```
$('.resizable').mousedown(function(e){
    dragging = true;
    $(this).addClass("moving");
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
    ... ... ...
        $('.moving p').html(percentageChange.toFixed(0));
    }       
   });
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
if (dragging){
    dragging = false;
    $(this).removeClass("moving");
}
```

Comment: Wow...sweet idea. I will give that a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Worked for the most part but with one caveat...when you drag the next bar both bars numbers continue to update.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle and share it ? That will help us to see where the problem is.